# How do I find equal columns in R?

Tags: r, equivalence

Given the following:

```
a <- c(1,2,3)
b <- c(1,2,3)
c <- c(4,5,6)
A <- cbind(a,b,c)
```

I want to find which columns in A are equal to for example my vector a.

My first attempt would be:

```
> which(a==A)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Which did not do that. (Too be honest I don't even understand what that did)
Second attempt was:

```
a==A
        a    b     c
[1,] TRUE TRUE FALSE
[2,] TRUE TRUE FALSE
[3,] TRUE TRUE FALSE
```

which definitely is a step in the right direction but it seems extended into a matrix. What I would have preferred is something like just one of the rows. How do I compare a vector to columns and how do I find columns in a matrix that are equal to a vector?

Comment: "Could not find function 'nbind'". Always cut n paste your code.

Comment: Fixed. (And adding some more text so I can press "Add Comment")

Comment: Protip: never test with a square matrix (too easy to confuse rows with columns). Not saying you have, but you will....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you add an extra row:

```
> A
     a b c  
[1,] 1 1 4 4
[2,] 2 2 5 2
[3,] 3 3 6 1
```

Then you can see that this function is correct:

```
> hasCol=function(A,a){colSums(a==A)==nrow(A)}
> A[,hasCol(A,a)]
     a b
[1,] 1 1
[2,] 2 2
[3,] 3 3
```

But the earlier version accepted doesn't:

```
> oopsCol=function(A,a){colSums(a==A)>0}
> A[,oopsCol(A,a)]
     a b  
[1,] 1 1 4
[2,] 2 2 2
[3,] 3 3 1
```

It returns the 4,2,1 column because the 2 matches the 2 in 1,2,3.

Comment: Why not use `all`?  I don't understand the point of converting a logical to a numeric in this situation.

Comment: I wanted to show and correct the bug in the accepted answer. Better answers are available!

Comment: @hadley Because there is no `colAlls` in R. I'll update my answer with a benchmark.

Answer (score 9):

Use `identical`. That is R's "scalar" comparison operator; it returns a single logical value, not a vector.

```
apply(A, 2, identical, a)
#    a     b     c 
# TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

If `A` is a data frame in your real case, you're better off using `sapply` or `vapply` because `apply` coerces it's input to a matrix.

```
d <- c("a", "b", "c")
B <- data.frame(a, b, c, d)

apply(B, 2, identical, a) # incorrect!
#     a     b     c     d 
# FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE 

sapply(B, identical, a) # correct
#    a     b     c     d 
# TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

But note that `data.frame` coerces character inputs to factors unless you ask otherwise:

```
sapply(B, identical, d) # incorrect
#     a     b     c     d 
# FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE 

C <- data.frame(a, b, c, d, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
sapply(C, identical, d) # correct
#     a     b     c     d 
# FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Identical is also considerably faster than using `all` + `==`:

```
library(microbenchmark)

a <- 1:1000
b <- c(1:999, 1001)

microbenchmark(
  all(a == b), 
  identical(a, b))
# Unit: microseconds
#              expr   min    lq median     uq    max
# 1     all(a == b) 8.053 8.149 8.2195 8.3295 17.355
# 2 identical(a, b) 1.082 1.182 1.2675 1.3435  3.635
```

Comment: @Spacedman `identical` will be even faster in situations where `==` would coerce or recycle.

Comment: Note that this will fail (and silently) if the vector you test against ('a') has any other attributes, such as names. `c(1,2,3)` is not identical to `c(n=1,m=2,x=3)` even though the values are the same. I'm wary of using `identical`.

Comment: @Spacedman Well personally, I'd consider those vectors different, but ymmv. As in any problem, you need to think about definition of equality you need.  Using `==` has it's own risks: `all(c(1,2) == c(1,2,1,2))`.

Comment: When do we need to use  all.equal() ?

Answer (score 4):

Surely there's a better solution but the following works:

```
> a <- c(1,2,3)
> b <- c(1,2,3)
> c <- c(4,5,6)
> A <- cbind(a,b,c)
> sapply(1:ncol(A), function(i) all(a==A[,i]))
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

And to get the indices:

```
> which(sapply(1:ncol(A), function(i) all(a==A[,i])))
[1] 1 2
```

Comment: I did something similar:  which(apply(A==a,2,all))

Answer (score -1):

```
colSums(a==A)==nrow(A)
```

Recycling of `==` makes `a` effectively a matrix which has all columns equal to `a` and dimensions equal to those of `A`. `colSums` sums each column; while `TRUE` behaves like 1 and `FALSE` like 0, columns equal to `a` will have sum equal to the number of rows. We use this observation to finally reduce the answer to a logical vector.

EDIT:

```
library(microbenchmark)

A<-rep(1:14,1000);c(7,2000)->dim(A)
1:7->a

microbenchmark(
 apply(A,2,function(b) identical(a,b)),
 apply(A,2,function(b) all(a==b)),
 colSums(A==a)==nrow(A))

# Unit: microseconds
#                                     expr      min        lq    median
# 1     apply(A, 2, function(b) all(a == b)) 9446.210 9825.6465 10278.335
# 2 apply(A, 2, function(b) identical(a, b)) 9324.203 9915.7935 10314.833
# 3               colSums(A == a) == nrow(A)  120.252  121.5885   140.185
#         uq       max
# 1 10648.7820 30588.765
# 2 10868.5970 13905.095
# 3   141.7035   162.858
```

Comment: Wrong! The >0 will be TRUE if any of the elements of 'a' match the element of the column of A. You need to check if all the values are TRUE, hence: colSums(a==A)==nrow(A)